# Zend_Paginator; is it optimized?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

I am about to use Zend_Paginator class in my project. I found examples of the class on the internet. One of them is

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name ';    
$result = $db->fetchAll($sql);    
$page=$this->_getParam('page',1);    
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($result);   
 $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10));   
 $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);   
 $this->view->paginator=$paginator;
```

on the first line, it actually select all the rows from table_name. What if I have a table with 50000 rows? That would be very inefficient.

Is there any other way to use Zend Paginator?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

About this problem, you might be interested by this section of the manual : [**39.2.2. The DbSelect and DbTableSelect adapter**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html#zend.paginator.usage.dbselect), which states *(quoting, emphasis mine)* :

> ... the database adapters require a
>   more detailed explanation. 
> Contrary to
>   popular believe, these adapters **do not
>   fetch all records from the database** in
>   order to count them.  
> Instead, the
>   adapters manipulates the original
>   query to produce the corresponding
>   `COUNT` query. 
> Paginator then executes
>   that `COUNT` query to get the number of
>   rows. 
> This does require an extra
>   round-trip to the database, but **this
>   is many times faster than fetching an
>   entire result set and using `count()`**.
>   
> Especially with large collections of
>   data.

*(There is more to read on that page -- and there is an example that should give you more information)*

The idea is that **you will not fetch all data yourself anymore**, but you'll tell to **`Zend_Paginator`** which Adapter it must use to access your data.

This Adapter will be specific to "*Data that is fetched via an SQL query*", and will know how to paginate it directly on the database side -- which means fetching only what is required, and not all data like you initialy did.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend passing a `Zend_Db_Select` object as `Zend_Paginator::factory($select);` rather than a passing a result rowset. Otherwise, you're selecting the entire result set and then doing the pagination. In your current solution, if you had a million rows, you'd select all of them before getting the chunk of rows defined by the current page.